# Can I use a mosfet to discharge quickly a capacitor without resistor?

Tags: capacitor, mosfet, resistors, solar-cell

I have to monitor a PV cell with a capacitor and to discharge I was thinking about using a mosfet whithout resistor to do it, whithout time constant. This, produce a short circuit when the discharge is on. Could I do that? What happen with the energy ?

Comment: The energy stored in the capacitor is dissipated as heat either in the capacitor or the transistor. If the discharge is very fast, the instantaneous power in the transistor can be surprisingly high.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a good idea. It may work OK if the capacitor is very small. But you will be operating the transistor in a pulse mode and you will have to refer to the peak pulse power allowable from the datasheet. It is always better to dissipate heat with a resistor rather than with silicon. Even a small resistor (a few ohms) will likely completely shift the power dissipation from the transistor to the resistor. Try to choose a resistor with a pulse power rating listed in the datasheet. Also, you may want to put a fuse in series so that if/when the mosfet fails, nothing catastrophic occurs. MOSFET's usually fail short.

Answer (score 2):

From offline computations, you'll have about 0.05 joules of heat storage in the silicon and the copper flag directly under the silicon, per degree C heating.

If you want only 100 degree C temperature rise, then the capacitor can only store 5 joules of energy.

==================================

here is the math

Assume the FET is 5mm by 5mm, atop a copper flag; assume the total thickness is 2mm. This is volume of 50 cubic milliMeters or (each mm^3 being 1,000,000,000 cubic microns) 50 Billion cubic microns. Or that is

0.05 Trillion cubic microns.

Now assume the thermal capacity of copper and silicon are the same, using the silicon value of 1.6 picoJoules per cubic micron per degree C.

Lets multiply our 2 numbers

0.05 Trillion cubic microns * 1.6 picoJoules per cubic micron per degree C

and we have

0.08 joules per degree C temperature rise.

Again, this is for the silicon and the copper immediately under the silicon.

Why is this important?

Because the thermal time constant to spread heat into the rest of the flag (the copper slab) is very slow: 1cm is 1.14 seconds, 4cm is 16X slower.

What is the time constant to dump heat from the silicon (probably 100 micron thick, atop 1.9? millimeter of copper?

Well, 1 cubic meter has time constant of 11,400 seconds.

1mm is 1000 * 1000 faster at 11.4 milliseconds (0.0114 seconds).

A 2mm thick slab is 4X slower at about 0.05 seconds.

Thus you **MUST** slow down the heat generation, to spread out over 0.05 seconds. or you will merely be heating the silicon so fast the heat cannot move down into the copper mounting slab (the TO-220 base_plate).

======================

answering the commentor: yes these are 63% τ just so the idea gets out there that total punt-and-hope is not needed.

Comment: Is that time constant the 63% time constant? Or the time it takes for heat to equalize (99+%)? If it is 63%, then shouldn't you need longer than 0.05 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Sound like a sample and hold circuit. You can discharge the capacitor with a mosfet. Just be aware the heat will be split between the mosfet rds on and the capacitor esr.

The amount of energy in a small capacitor should not be an issue. But things will get warm depending on how often.

P = I<sup>2</sup> x R, so for an accurate wattage if your conscerned you would need to find the rms current over the discharge time.

Comment: Ok. So,I have to watch out with the heat and do it quickly according to the maximum safe operating area from the mosfet. Keeping in mind this, although the simulation simulate the short circuit (controlated), this won't be a problem in the real circuit, not?

Comment: The capacitor has ESR, the mosfet has on resistance, add them to your simulation, you will have a current peak, somewhere close to Vcap / (Rfet + Rcap)